# Tinymce remove <!doctype> and <html> tags

Tags: tinymce, doctype

I'm trying to extract just the html, without the encapsulating `<!doctype>`, `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

I've seen this question asked before many times, and the answer is always to exclude the "fullpage" plugin.

However, that plugin is [no longer used in tinymce 6](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/fullpage/).

It seems that the classic editor version of tinymce now always uses an `<iframe>`, and those unfortunate encapsulating tags are passed along as a consequence.

For the sake of robustness I don't want to have to strip them out in the back end if I can help it; is there a way to extract just the html content in tinymce 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to provide more details on what you are doing when you extract the content from TinyMCE.

In my quick testing simply using getContent() to extract the data from TinyMCE does not include any of those tags:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/MChaab/3

Comment: Thank you for that! I did not know about tinymce fiddle. getContent() seems to work for my case (though requires javascript to be fired on form submit, but that's probably OK).

I'm using with a Laravel form, and have just been implementing based on the classic editor example in the docs (I'm having real trouble following the docs at the moment, they seem all over the place to me - but here is the closes I can find at the moment: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/classic-demo/).

I've been using php's DomDocument to remove the html encapsulation, but your alternative is useful thanks!